# How to open a thread whose target is in another file?

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to open a thread whose target is defined in a different file.

I would like to pass the target name through a string containing, of course, the name of the function I want to run on thread.
Is that impossible, or am I missing something?

For instance, here is my code:

Here is the code that has the target function:

```
# command.py

def hello():
    print("hello world")
```

and here is the code I will run:

```
# run.py

import threading
import commands

funcname = "hello"

thread1 = threading.Thread(target= ... , daemon=True)
thread1.start()
```

What do i need to put as target?

Answer (score 0):

From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) the `target` has to be a callable object. From your example you should be able to just put

`target=command.hello`

Comment: Yeah, but how do I "extract" the callable object hello from the string funcname?

Comment: [see this issue on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

You can do it like `getattr(commands, funcname)()`

Comment: or like `thread1 = threading.Thread(target=getattr(commands, funcname), ...)`